# Node.js script may have memory leak

Tags: javascript, memory-management, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I use this node.js script to migrate MongoDB collection to a schema to another. It does work if the collection is <20k documents, but slows down to a crawl and sometime throw a

> FATAL ERROR: JS Allocation failed - process out of memory

Is it because of a memory leak? Or the intensive call to `process.nextTick()` (once per document)?

My guess is that if the mongoDB server fast enough to the save/too many documents, callback piles up and eat the CPU/RAM away and end up crashing the script.

Is my guess right? Is there a memory leak? What can I do to speed up the script/fix existing error(s)?

```
    var fs = require('fs'),
    mongoose = require('mongoose'),
    db = {},     //db.read will be the connection to the collection to migrate, db.write to the collection to migrate to
    S_logs = {}, //Mongoose schema (read and write)
    M_logs = {}, //Mongoose models (read and write)
    config,      //Config file
    launched = 0,//Number of document migration started
    ended = 0,   //Number of document migration finished
    percent = 0, //Used to calculate the progress bar
    stats = {
        ok: 0,   //Number of succesful migration
        error: 0 //Number of failed migration
    };

function getCollection(callback) {
    console.log('|0%      |10%      |20%      |30%      |40%      |50%      |60%      |70%      |80%      |90%      |100%')
    M_logs.read.count({}, function (err, count) {
        var stream = M_logs.read.find().stream(); //Stream the entire collection, document by document

        stream.on('data', function (document) {
            launched = launched + 1;
            //Adapt the document to the new schema
            var P_log = {};
            for (name in config.write.data) {
                if (config.write.data.hasOwnProperty(name)) {
                    P_log[name] = document[name] || '';
                }
            }
            //Clear the queue
            process.nextTick(function () {
                //Save the new document
                new M_logs.write(P_log).save(function (err) {
                    //Update the progress bar
                    while(ended > ((percent * count)/100)) {
                        process.stdout.write('-');
                        percent = percent + 1;
                    }
                    //Update the stats
                    if(err) {
                        stats.error = stats.error + 1;
                    } else {
                        stats.ok = stats.ok + 1;
                    }
                    ended = ended + 1;
                });
            });
        }).on('error', function (err) {
            launched = launched + 1;
            while(ended > ((percent * count)/100)) {
                process.stdout.write('-');
                percent = percent + 1;
            }
            ended = ended + 1;
        }).on('close', function () {
            process.nextTick(function (){
                //Wait for all transfert to end
                var wait = setInterval(function () {
                    if(ended === launched) {
                        clearInterval(wait);
                        console.log('\nTransfert lancé:   ' + launched);
                        console.log('Transfert terminé: ' + ended);
                        callback();
                    }
                }, 1000);
            });
        });
    });
}

function connect(callback) {
    db.read = mongoose.createConnection(config.read.url);

    db.read.on('error', console.error.bind(console, 'connection error:'));
    db.read.once('open', function () {

        db.write = mongoose.createConnection(config.write.url);
        db.write.on('error', console.error.bind(console, 'connection error:'));
        db.write.once('open', function () {

            S_logs.read = new mongoose.Schema(
                config.read.data,
                {
                    strict: false,
                    collection: config.read.base
                }
            );

            M_logs.read = db.read.model(config.read.base, S_logs.read, config.read.base);

            S_logs.write = new mongoose.Schema(
                config.write.data,
                {
                    collection: config.write.base
                }
            );

            S_logs.write.index(config.write.index, {unique: true});

            M_logs.write = db.write.model(config.write.base, S_logs.write, config.write.base);

            callback();
        });
    });
}

process.stdout.write('Reading config');
fs.readFile(process.argv[2] || 'config.js', function (err, data) {
    if (err) {
        console.log('Error in config.js:' + err);
        process.exit();
    }
    config = JSON.parse(data);
    console.log('...OK');
    console.log('From ' + config.read.url + ' / ' + config.read.base);
    console.log('To   ' + config.write.url + ' / ' + config.write.base);
    process.stdout.write('Connecting to Mongo')
    connect(function () {
        console.log('...OK');
        getCollection(function () {
            console.log('OK: ' + stats.ok + ' / Error: ' + stats.error);
            process.exit();
        });
    });
});
```

Exemple of config file:

```
{
    "read":
    {
        "url" : "mongodb://localhost/read",
        "base" : "read_collection",
        "data": 
        {
            "user_ip" : "String",
            "user_id" : "String",
            "user_agent" : "String",
            "canal_id" : "String",
            "theme_id" : "String",
            "video_id" : "String",
            "time" : "Number",
            "action" : "String",
            "is_newuser" : "String",
            "operator" : "String",
            "template" : "String",
            "catalogue" : "String",
            "referer" : "String",
            "from" : "String",
            "request" : "String",
            "smil" : "String",
            "smil_path" : "String"
        }
    },
    "write":
    {
        "url" : "mongodb://localhost/write",
        "base" : "write_collection",
        "data": 
        {
            "user_ip" : "String",
            "user_id" : "String",
            "user_agent" : "String",
            "canal_id" : "String",
            "theme_id" : "String",
            "pays" : "String",
            "lang" : "String",
            "video_id" : "String",
            "time" : "Number",
            "action" : "String",
            "is_newuser" : "String",
            "operator" : "String",
            "template" : "String",
            "catalogue" : "String",
            "referer" : "String",
            "from" : "String",
            "request" : "String",
            "smil" : "String",
            "smil_path" : "String"
        },
        "index" : 
        {
            "user_ip" : 1,
            "user_id" : 1,
            "time" : 1
        }
    }
}
```

Looking at the CPU and RAM usage while the script try to transfer a 500k documents collection, I can see that the CPU is not really a issue (oscillating between 50% and 75% max), but RAM slowly but steadily grow. My guess is I should find a way to regulate the number of document waiting for a answer of the mongoDB server, and pause the streaming until that number as fall to a reasonably low level...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Interesting question,

It seems you are using a ton of closures. 13 out of 15 `function` definitions are anonymous functions. I cant find a single one that is capturing anything useful since you have a ton of global variables on top.

I would simply declare every one of those functions as a named function, it should already help a ton. And then indeed build some queue so that you are not DOS'ing your own machine.

Comment: For separating the code, I can do that. But I don't really see how I can make the queueing. Should calculate the difference between `launched` and `ended` and pause the streaming if the difference is over X will be enough? Or should I search more advanced algorithm? (Or should I ask thoses question on Programmers instead of Code Review?)

Comment: Please look into functional reactive programming, there are some excellent js libraries to help you out with this dilemma. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Functional_reactive_programming

Answer (score 0):

As a way of closing this question:

I named all function, here the result:

```
var fs = require('fs'),
    mongoose = require('mongoose'),
    db = {},
    S_logs = {},
    M_logs = {},
    config,
    percent = 0;

function updateProgressBar(launched, ended, percent, count) {
    // while(ended > ((percent * count)/100)) {
    //     process.stdout.write('-');
    //     percent = percent + 1;
    // }
    console.log(launched + ' / ' + ended + ' / ' + count);
}

function migrate(stream, count, read, write, callback) {
    var launched = 0,
        ended = 0,
        stats = {
            ok: 0,
            error: 0
        },
        wait,
        progressBar,
        queue;
    console.log('|0%      |10%      |20%      |30%      |40%      |50%      |60%      |70%      |80%      |90%      |100%');

    progressBar = setInterval(function () {
        updateProgressBar(launched, ended, percent, count);
    }, 1000);

    queue = setInterval(function () {
        if(!stream.paused && (launched - ended) > 50000) {
            stream.pause();
            console.log('PAUSE');
        } else if(stream.paused && (launched - ended) <= 25000) {
            stream.resume();
            console.log('RESUME');
        }
    }, 1000);

    stream.on('data', function (document) {
        launched = launched + 1;
        var P_log = {};
        for (name in config.write.data) {
            if (config.write.data.hasOwnProperty(name)) {
                P_log[name] = document[name] || '';
            }
        }
        process.nextTick(function () {
            new write(P_log).save(function (err) {
                if(err) {
                    stats.error = stats.error + 1;
                } else {
                    stats.ok = stats.ok + 1;
                }
                ended = ended + 1;
            });
        });
    }).on('error', function (err) {
        console.log('ERR: ' + err);
        process.exit();
    }).on('close', function () {
        if(launched === count) {
            console.log('CLOSE');
            process.nextTick(function (){
                wait = setInterval(function () {
                    if(ended === launched) {
                        clearInterval(wait);
                        clearInterval(progressBar);
                        clearInterval(queue);
                        console.log('\nTransfert lancé:   ' + launched);
                        console.log('Transfert terminé: ' + ended);
                        callback(stats);
                    }
                }, 1000);
            });
        }
    });
}

function getCollection(callback) {
    M_logs.read.count({}, function (err, count) {
        var stream = M_logs.read.find().stream();
        callback(stream, count);
    });
}

function connect(callback) {
    //Se connecte a mongoDB au travers de mongoose, crée les shemas et modeles mongoose neccessaire, et lance l'ecooute sur le port 8080
    db.read = mongoose.createConnection(config.read.url);          //Creer la connexion a mongodb

    db.read.on('error', console.error.bind(console, 'connection error:'));
    db.read.once('open', function () {                                       //Une fois connecte

        db.write = mongoose.createConnection(config.write.url);          //Creer la connexion a mongodb
        db.write.on('error', console.error.bind(console, 'connection error:'));
        db.write.once('open', function () {                                       //Une fois connecte

            S_logs.read = new mongoose.Schema(
                config.read.data,
                {
                    strict: false,
                    collection: config.read.base
                }
            );

            M_logs.read = db.read.model(config.read.base, S_logs.read, config.read.base);

            S_logs.write = new mongoose.Schema(
                config.write.data,
                {
                    collection: config.write.base
                }
            );

            S_logs.write.index(config.write.index, {unique: true});

            M_logs.write = db.write.model(config.write.base, S_logs.write, config.write.base);

            callback();
        });
    });
}

process.stdout.write('Reading config');
fs.readFile(process.argv[2] || 'config.js', function (err, data) {
    if (err) {
        console.log('Error in config.js:' + err);
        process.exit();
    }
    // console.log('' + data);
    config = JSON.parse(data);
    console.log('...OK');
    console.log('From ' + config.read.url + ' / ' + config.read.base);
    console.log('To   ' + config.write.url + ' / ' + config.write.base);
    process.stdout.write('Connecting to Mongo')
    //Se connecter a MongoDB
    connect(function () {
        console.log('...OK');
        //Parser les fichiers
        getCollection(function (stream, count) {
            migrate(stream, count, M_logs.read, M_logs.write, function (stats) {
                console.log('OK: ' + stats.ok + ' / Error: ' + stats.error);
                process.exit();
            });
        });
    });
});
```

But even after that, I still had to makje the queue, and had problem with `QueryStream.pause()` and `QueryStream.resume()`, so I dumped `QueryStream` altogether (it s a internal tool, I just need something that work most of the time), the end result is far more slow, but don t have any memory problem:

```
var fs = require('fs'),
    mongoose = require('mongoose'),
    db = {},
    S_logs = {},
    M_logs = {},
    config,
    launched = 0,
    ended = 0,
    percent = 0,
    stats = {
        ok: 0,
        error: 0
    };

function migrate(i, count, callback) {
    // console.log('migrate ' + i);
    // console.log(ended + '/' + count);
    var query = M_logs.read.find().limit(5000).skip(i * 5000),
        wait,
        end = 0;
    query.exec(function (err, docs) {
        docs.forEach(function (document) {
            var P_log = {};
            for (name in config.write.data) {
                if (config.write.data.hasOwnProperty(name)) {
                    P_log[name] = document[name] || '';
                }
            }
            process.nextTick(function () {
                new M_logs.write(P_log).save(function (err) {
                    while(ended > ((percent * count)/100)) {
                        process.stdout.write('-');
                        percent = percent + 1;
                    }
                    if(err) {
                        stats.error = stats.error + 1;
                    } else {
                        stats.ok = stats.ok + 1;
                    }
                    ended = ended + 1;
                    end = end + 1;
                });
            });
        });
        wait = setInterval(function () {
            if(end === docs.length) {
                clearInterval(wait);
                callback(i);
            }
        }, 1000);
    });
}

function migrateAll(i, count, callback) {
    if(ended < count) {
        migrate(i, count, function () {
            migrateAll(i + 1, count, callback);
        });
    } else {
        callback();
    }
}

function getCollection(callback) {
    console.log('|0%      |10%      |20%      |30%      |40%      |50%      |60%      |70%      |80%      |90%      |100%')
    M_logs.read.count({}, function (err, count) {
        migrateAll(0, count, function() {
            callback();
        });
    });
}

function connect(callback) {
    //Se connecte a mongoDB au travers de mongoose, crée les shemas et modeles mongoose neccessaire, et lance l'ecooute sur le port 8080
    db.read = mongoose.createConnection(config.read.url);          //Creer la connexion a mongodb

    db.read.on('error', console.error.bind(console, 'connection error:'));
    db.read.once('open', function () {                                       //Une fois connecte

        db.write = mongoose.createConnection(config.write.url);          //Creer la connexion a mongodb
        db.write.on('error', console.error.bind(console, 'connection error:'));
        db.write.once('open', function () {                                       //Une fois connecte

            S_logs.read = new mongoose.Schema(
                config.read.data,
                {
                    strict: false,
                    collection: config.read.base
                }
            );

            M_logs.read = db.read.model(config.read.base, S_logs.read, config.read.base);

            S_logs.write = new mongoose.Schema(
                config.write.data,
                {
                    collection: config.write.base
                }
            );

            S_logs.write.index(config.write.index, {unique: true});

            M_logs.write = db.write.model(config.write.base, S_logs.write, config.write.base);

            callback();
        });
    });
}

process.stdout.write('Reading config');
fs.readFile(process.argv[2] || 'config.js', function (err, data) {
    if (err) {
        console.log('Error in config.js:' + err);
        process.exit();
    }
    // console.log('' + data);
    config = JSON.parse(data);
    console.log('...OK');
    console.log('From ' + config.read.url + ' / ' + config.read.base);
    console.log('To   ' + config.write.url + ' / ' + config.write.base);
    process.stdout.write('Connecting to Mongo')
    //Se connecter a MongoDB
    connect(function () {
        console.log('...OK');
        //Parser les fichiers
        getCollection(function () {
            console.log('OK: ' + stats.ok + ' / Error: ' + stats.error);
            process.exit();
        });
    });
});
```